# Using BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH to define macros

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c-preprocessor

In the example in boost's documentation about `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` the show how to use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH` and `(w)(x)(y)(z)` to expand to `w_ x_ y_ z_`.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each.html
This is nice but I need it to expand to

```
#define w _
#define x _
#define y _
#define z _
```

If I use `#define MACRO_DEFINE(r, data, elem) #define elem data` and `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO_DEFINE, _, SEQ)` I get the following compilation error `error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter`. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: There is no way to do that. A macro cannot expand to a preprocessor directive. There's no clever trick or workaround.

Comment: Indeed this simple program

    #define A #define B 0
    A
    int main() { return B;}

also does not compile, the error is `error: stray ‘#’ in program`. So I understand this is a lost case :-(

Comment: Now that we shot down your attempt mercilessly, you can describe the problem this would have resolved and see if there's another way ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to do it?

It is not possible to do that. It's not possible to define a macro from inside a macro. You have to write it out.